# Favicon image in the image tag issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, favicon

I am trying to load the favicon image in the image tag. 
Its working on all browsers except IE.

Here is the code
<img alt="" src="http://techcrunch.com/favicon.ico">

Can you please help me to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find an official list of image types supported by Internet Explorer, but ICO indeed doesn't seem to be supported as an image format (which is ironic because it was IE that introduced the ICO format into the favicons thing in the first place). It's not working for me in IE8 either - see a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pW646/).

There's probably nothing you can do to change that. The only solution that comes to mind is writing a server-side script that fetches the ICO file, converts it into PNG or JPG, and serves it to you.